# React js show hidden div when select option is selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

how can we show or hide a div when the selected option is changed,
I have 1 select dropdown, with 3 options, want to show or hide a div when the option is changed,
trying to go with setState but no luck,

```
   state={
     showOption: false,
   }

   handleOptionChange = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.setState({
      showOption : true
    }) 
    console.log('changed')
   }

   <select className="form-control">
      <option  value="option one">option one</option>
      <option value="option two"
        onChange={this.hadleOptionChange}
      >option two</option>
      <option value="option three">option three</option>
   </select>

    <div>
     {this.state.showOption}
     <div className="form-group">
       <label>Number one should hide or show when option one is cliked</label>
       <input type="text"  name="" className="form-control"/>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: (That [mcve] can be runnable using Stack Snippets, the `[<>]` toolbar button. Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).)

Comment: Have you tried to make a little research? This is pretty basic, I'd advise to follow the 'Get started' page of React, follow the tutorial and you'll know how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the way you're trying to use `this.state.showOption`:

```
 {this.state.showOption} // this doesn't do anything
 <div className="form-group">
   <label>Number one should hide or show when option one is cliked</label>
   <input type="text"  name="" className="form-control"/>
 </div>
```

Change it to:

```
 {this.state.showOption && // if it's true return the actual JSX
 <div className="form-group">
   <label>Number one should hide or show when option one is cliked</label>
   <input type="text"  name="" className="form-control"/>
 </div>
 }
```

This is called [short circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation). As long as the the expression `this.state.showOption` is `false`, the expression returns `false` (which React ignores). If `this.state.showOption` is `true` the evaluation continues, and the JSX is returned and rendered by React.

In addition as [@TKoL commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59423203/react-js-show-hidden-div-when-select-option-is-selected/59423262#comment105032860_59423262) you should move the `onChange` event handler to the `select` tag. You should also add the `value={this.state.showOption}`:

```
<select className="form-control"
  value={this.state.showOption}
  onChange={this.handleOptionChange}>
  <option value="option one">option one</option>
  <option value="option two">option two</option>
  <option value="option three">option three</option>
</select>
```

You can find an example of React's handling of controlled select component [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag).

Comment: That is one problem, but it's not the only problem. The other problem is that his `onChange={this.hadleOptionChange}` prop is on the `<option>` rathern than on the containing `<select>`. I'm not 100% sure, but I don't believe it works that way

Comment: Thanks for the answer,
have a little confusion here, can we update the value of select on the basis of options

Comment: because for every option there are respective divs, so need to hide/show divs
hope this screen short makes sense https://prnt.sc/qdgpmo

Comment: You can use `this.state.showOption &&` for option, and `this.state.showOption ||` for the other. Look at the link I've added that explains short circuit evaluation.